# HTTP request as bytes

Tags: arduino-uno

I need to send this line of HTTP request as bytes. What is the correct way?

```
client.write(byte(" <? xml version: '1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><VideoOverlay><normalizedScreenSize><normalizedScreenWidth>704</normalizedScreenWidth><normalizedScreenHeight>576</normalizedScreenHeight></normalizedScreenSize><attribute><transparent>false</transparent><flashing>false</flashing></attribute><fontSize>adaptive</fontSize><frontColorMode>auto</frontColorMode><alignment>customize</alignment><TextOverlayList><TextOverlay><id>1</id><enabled>true</enabled><displayText>dsadasdasdas</displayText><positionX>0</positionX><positionY>480</positionY></TextOverlay></TextOverlayList><DateTimeOverlay><enabled>true</enabled><positionY>544</positionY><positionX>0</positionX><dateStyle>MM-DD-YYYY</dateStyle><timeStyle>24hour</timeStyle><displayWeek>true</displayWeek></DateTimeOverlay><channelNameOverlay><enabled>true</enabled><positionY>64</positionY><positionX>16</positionX></channelNameOverlay></VideoOverlay>"));
```

To be more clear this is my C# code for the request

```
byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(" <? xml version: '1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><VideoOverlay><normalizedScreenSize><normalizedScreenWidth>704</normalizedScreenWidth><normalizedScreenHeight>576</normalizedScreenHeight></normalizedScreenSize><attribute><transparent>false</transparent><flashing>false</flashing></attribute><fontSize>adaptive</fontSize><frontColorMode>auto</frontColorMode><alignment>customize</alignment><TextOverlayList><TextOverlay><id>1</id><enabled>true</enabled><displayText>" + textBox1.Text + "</displayText><positionX>0</positionX><positionY>480</positionY></TextOverlay></TextOverlayList><DateTimeOverlay><enabled>true</enabled><positionY>544</positionY><positionX>0</positionX><dateStyle>MM-DD-YYYY</dateStyle><timeStyle>24hour</timeStyle><displayWeek>true</displayWeek></DateTimeOverlay><channelNameOverlay><enabled>true</enabled><positionY>64</positionY><positionX>16</positionX></channelNameOverlay></VideoOverlay>");
```

This is my full C# working code

```
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(" <? xml version: '1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><VideoOverlay><normalizedScreenSize><normalizedScreenWidth>704</normalizedScreenWidth><normalizedScreenHeight>576</normalizedScreenHeight></normalizedScreenSize><attribute><transparent>false</transparent><flashing>false</flashing></attribute><fontSize>adaptive</fontSize><frontColorMode>auto</frontColorMode><alignment>customize</alignment><TextOverlayList><TextOverlay><id>1</id><enabled>true</enabled><displayText>" + textBox1.Text + "</displayText><positionX>0</positionX><positionY>480</positionY></TextOverlay></TextOverlayList><DateTimeOverlay><enabled>true</enabled><positionY>544</positionY><positionX>0</positionX><dateStyle>MM-DD-YYYY</dateStyle><timeStyle>24hour</timeStyle><displayWeek>true</displayWeek></DateTimeOverlay><channelNameOverlay><enabled>true</enabled><positionY>64</positionY><positionX>16</positionX></channelNameOverlay></VideoOverlay>");
        Uri a = new Uri("http://192.168.0.64");
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.64/ISAPI/System/Video/inputs/channels/1/overlays") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "12345qwerty");
        request.ContentLength = 888;
        request.ContentType = "application / x - www - form - urlencoded; charset = UTF - 8";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        response.Close();
```

This is the Arduino version

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 0, 177 };
byte server[] = { 192,168, 0, 64}; // Google
String big_string="<?xml versiding='rlay>";
EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
  Ethernet.begin(ip);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("connecting...");

  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.println("POST /ISAPI/System/Video/inputs/channels/1/overlays HTTP/1.0");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.0.64");
    client.println("User-Agent: arduino-ethernet");
    client.println("Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDVxd2VydHk=");
   client.println("Content-Type: application / x - www - form - urlencoded; charset = UTF - 8");

    client.println("content-length:888");
    // client.println();
    //client.println(big_string.length());
    client.write(" <? xml version: '1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><VideoOverlay><normalizedScreenSize><normalizedScreenWidth>704</normalizedScreenWidth><normalizedScreenHeight>576</normalizedScreenHeight></normalizedScreenSize><attribute><transparent>false</transparent><flashing>false</flashing></attribute><fontSize>adaptive</fontSize><frontColorMode>auto</frontColorMode><alignment>customize</alignment><TextOverlayList><TextOverlay><id>1</id><enabled>true</enabled><displayText>dsadasdasdas</displayText><positionX>0</positionX><positionY>480</positionY></TextOverlay></TextOverlayList><DateTimeOverlay><enabled>true</enabled><positionY>544</positionY><positionX>0</positionX><dateStyle>MM-DD-YYYY</dateStyle><timeStyle>24hour</timeStyle><displayWeek>true</displayWeek></DateTimeOverlay><channelNameOverlay><enabled>true</enabled><positionY>64</positionY><positionX>16</positionX></channelNameOverlay></VideoOverlay>");

     //client.println();
    //client.print(big_string);
    // client.println();






  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you think that you have to send the request as `bytes`?

Comment: Because i have a c# aplication that works with sending the request as bytes , in order for the ip camera to read them , and now i need to do the same for the arduino

Comment: why do you think that a string character, such as an `x` is not a byte?

Comment: this appears to be an example of an X-Y problem ...... you are asking for help with what you consider to be a solution to your problem, but you withhold the details of the original problem

Comment: first reduce the C# code. remove lines with request.ContentLength = 888 and request.ContentType. they are wrong so could be ignored. Uri a = new Uri("http://192.168.0.64"); is not used. remove it

Comment: post your Arduino version too

Comment: I posted my Arduino version

Comment: remove the trailing space from " <xml. in C# version you send correct Content-length. In arduino you send 888. the type must by without spaces `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I changed it , still nothing

Comment: For one it's `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>` and `"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"``. Secondly you specify the content-length to be 888, while the string above is 895 characters long. Thirdy the data you send isn't actually `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but most likely the server doesn't care about this. Lastly, you haven't told us what the actual problem is. What doesn't work? Where does the C# code come into play here?

Comment: My problem is that nothing is sent to the camera , i need the arduino to send text to the ip camera display

Answer (score 0):

Characters are bytes. ASCII codes of characters are the values. There is no difference between `client.print(str)` and `client.write(str, strlen(str))`. And `client.write(str)` is the same too.

In C# or Java the constant string is of type String. It is an object. You must call a method of the object to get the raw char/byte array. In Arduino a constant string is of type `const char*` a.k.a. `const char[]` which is on low level the same as `const byte*` or `const byte[]`

Equivalent of C#

`byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes("some string");`

for ASCII characters (not UTF) in C is

`byte data[] = "some string";`

Comment: I read that (client.write) send bytes and (client.pritnln) sends string and chars etc , i understand your answer.  but i think it needs to be like my c# code that i edited in my question

Comment: in C# the constant string is of type String. it is an object. You must call a function to get the char/byte array. in Arduino a constant string is of type `const char*` a.k.a. `const char[]` which is on low level the same as `const byte*` or `const byte[]`

Comment: And what would be the way to do this ? sorry i am not that good in programming and i am having a little hard time with the bytes array

Comment: without `byte(`. it does wrong

Comment: One more question what about the Json library ? can it be used for this problem ?

Comment: this is xml, not json

Comment: you have a working C# code and can't rewrite it to Arduino?

Comment: Yeah i have the full working code on c# but cant rewrite it to Arduino

Comment: I posted it in my question