# How to convert string to byte array on arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

Well my title pretty much sums it up , how to convert string to byte array? i cant find any usefull code

Comment: You asked this already and I answered it here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/58105/http-request-as-bytes/58106#58106

Answer (score 0):

Well, the C string is already byte array.

If you mean Arduino's `String` class, then it has `c_str()` method.

Both needs reinterpret cast to const byte pointer:

```
byte const* byteArray = reinterpret_cast<byte const*>(yourString.c_str());
```

Comment: Yeah the Arduinos String , i did not understand the last line , i am sorry if i post stupid questions and i am new to all of this so i dont have experience

Comment: What did you ment by reinterpret cast to const byte pointer?

Comment: @Ivanh23 There is a difference between char and byte signedness so it must be cast by reinterpret_cast. I've added it into the answer.  But be warned, it's valid only as long as the yourString exists and wasn't changed. If you change the yourString, you have to get correct pointer again.